# Will this solid state drive fit in a Lenovo x220 tablet?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, lenovo-laptop

Verbatim 120GB SATA III 2.5" Internal SSD, found at
http://1saleaday.com/wireless/. Will this fit into my Lenovo X220 tablet, the one with an i5 processor, 320GB HDD, and 4GB RAM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All (?) laptops I know of use 2.5" hard drives (SSDs are the same form factor). Based on my experience with five generations of Lenovo thinkpads, I think the answer is automatically "yes".

Also the SATA controller on the X220 supports SATA 6GB/s so you don't have to worry about compatibility mode, etc. since that Verbatim is "SATA III" (a misnomer but that *should* mean SATA 6GB/s).

**Be careful**!!!! 2.5" disk drives come in two vertical (height) form factors: 7mm and 9mm! If your unit only supports "slim" 7mm form factor drives, you will **not** be able to install 9mm drives such as the one you posted in your question! This information taken from @MJD's answer which honestly should be the correct answer to this question. Please don't buy a 9mm drive for a 7mm "slim" formfactor laptop!

Comment: alright, thanks! I assume i will have to re-install an OS, since there is probably no way to copy my current windows with programs over?

Comment: (ill accept in 6 minutes, the minimum time)

Comment: If the unit only has one drive bay (I think that is the case for all X-series units), the only way to transfer data would be to stick the new disk into an external 2.5" disk enclosure and transfer using a boot disk or Live CD, e.g. SystemRescueCD or Ubuntu. Very possible, but slightly technically challenging and requires you to own or acquire or borrow a 2.5" enclosure. They're not very expensive though.

Comment: I could re-install Win8 release preview (what im running) on the new one, and by changing them out and re-bootnig, copy everything over via 16GB Flash Drive

Comment: If you need to know how to transfer data at the block layer from one disk drive to another, instead of asking another question, you should probably use the search feature of superuser (or Google). There are dozens upon dozens of different ways to do this effectively, but none of them get around the hardware requirement I mentioned

Comment: You can also reinstall the operating system and use some kind of USB storage media to back up the files/data you're interested in, as you suggested, yes. But many people want to avoid this because it requires re-activating your copy of Windows with Microsoft. I guess you don't care since you're using the preview..

Comment: Yeah, I may just wait till school starts again and get the tech lady to image it for me...This way office, etc, is installed and i can have it legally.

Comment: I could then overwrite win7 with the win8 RP

Comment: @allquixotic, not all laptops have 2.5'' hard drives, e.g. T400s, T410s and others have 1.8'' hard drives

Answer (score 5):

While the drive and your laptop are both 2.5", that drive is a 9mm high drive.  The x220T (and the x220) do not take a 9mm drive due to their slim size.  You must use a 7mm high drive (such as [this OCZ drive.](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820227803)  Some 9mm maybe modifiable to fit the 7mm height, however that will definitely void your warranty on the drive.

Comment: Wasn't aware that now we have to take height into account... :/ Thanks for the clarification; I recommend that this be made the correct answer to this question. OP, don't hit the "Order" button yet!!! Someone should mod my question down... ugh... I gave WRONG information without realizing it.

Answer (score 0):

Since it uses a 2.5", yes. Make sure you read the [manual](http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/0a60175.pdf) on how to replace it, or even [watch a video on how to do it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBjxSMmA45o).